# Ember.js Calling model's method from controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-controllers

Is there any way to get a hand on the model from a controller? I would need to call an instance method defined on the model and

```
this.get(methodName)(params)
```

does not work, as it loses the 'this' call context within the called function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which context you want to exist in the method, if you need to switch the context you can use call/apply.  The context should be the context of the method, not the controller by javascript standards.

```
var model = this.get('model');

model.methodName(arg1, arg2);
```

### Controller's context

```
model.methodName.apply(this, arrayOfArgs);

model.methodName.call(this, arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: Thanks, man! This question was really stupid, had tried calling this.get('model') but was in a jQuery handler by accident and the 'this' was pointing to something different, hence the strive to do this.get('methodName')(params)

Comment: And another big thank you for repetedly helping me with my Ember journey. You seem to be one of the few active Ember guys around SO.